# ASA conn flags explain

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, tcp, firewall

I have seen following output, but what is the difference between `UB` vs `UIOB` vs `UIO`?

I looked at this website, and it has nice explanation, but I am having a hard time to decode it in context: https://www.tunnelsup.com/understanding-cisco-asa-connection-flags/

```
fw/pri/act# sh conn
21 in use, 600 most used

TCP ext_dmz  10.5.8.40:33882 int_dmz  10.5.16.39:9090, idle 0:06:17, bytes 0, flags UB
TCP ext_dmz  10.5.8.40:60713 int_dmz  10.5.16.39:9090, idle 0:00:03, bytes 561603, flags UIOB
TCP ext_dmz  10.5.8.39:5432 int_dmz  10.5.16.40:53600, idle 0:00:06, bytes 44857, flags UIO
TCP outside  10.5.255.3:57229 inside  65.194.212.101:22, idle 0:00:45, bytes 395449, flags UIOB
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cisco maintains many documents, and all you need to do is search. For example, [*ASA TCP Connection Flags (Connection Build-Up and Teardown)*](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/113602-ptn-113602.html):

> ### ASA TCP Connection Flags
>
> When you troubleshoot TCP connections through the Adaptive Security
>   Appliance (ASA), the connection flags shown for each TCP connection
>   provide a wealth of information about the state of TCP connections to
>   the ASA. This information can be used to troubleshoot problems with
>   the ASA, as well as problems elsewhere in the network.
>
> Here is the output of the **show conn protocol tcp** command, which
>   shows the state of all TCP connections through the ASA. These
>   connections can also be seen with the **show conn** command.
>
> ```
> ASA# show conn protocol tcp
> 101 in use, 5589 most used
> TCP outside 10.23.232.59:5223 inside 192.168.1.3:52419, idle 0:00:11, bytes 0, flags saA
> TCP outside 192.168.3.5:80 dmz 172.16.103.221:57646, idle 0:00:29, bytes 2176, flags UIO
> TCP outside 10.23.232.217:5223 inside 192.168.1.3:52425, idle 0:00:10, bytes 0, flags saA
> TCP outside 10.23.232.217:443 inside 192.168.1.3:52427, idle 0:01:02, bytes 4504, flags UIO
> TCP outside 10.23.232.57:5223 inside 192.168.1.3:52412, idle 0:00:23, bytes 0, flags saA
> TCP outside 10.23.232.116:5223 inside 192.168.1.3:52408, idle 0:00:23, bytes 0, flags saA
> TCP outside 10.23.232.60:5223 inside 192.168.1.3:52413, idle 0:00:23, bytes 0, flags saA
> TCP outside 10.23.232.96:5223 inside 192.168.1.3:52421, idle 0:00:11, bytes 0, flags saA
> TCP outside 10.23.232.190:5223 inside 192.168.1.3:52424, idle 0:00:10, bytes 0, flags saA
> ```
>
> The next picture shows the ASA TCP Connection flags at different
>   stages of the TCP state machine. The connection flags can be seen with
>   the show conn command on the ASA.
>
> [image]
>
> Additionally, in order to view all of the possible connection flags
>   issue the show connection detail command on the command-line:
>
> ```
> ASA5515-X# show conn detail
> 35 in use, 199 most used
> Flags: A - awaiting inside ACK to SYN, a - awaiting outside ACK to SYN,
>        B - initial SYN from outside, b - TCP state-bypass or nailed,
>        C - CTIQBE media, c - cluster centralized,
>        D - DNS, d - dump, E - outside back connection, F - outside FIN, f - inside FIN,
>        G - group, g - MGCP, H - H.323, h - H.225.0, I - inbound data,
>        i - incomplete, J - GTP, j - GTP data, K - GTP t3-response
>        k - Skinny media, M - SMTP data, m - SIP media, n - GUP
>        O - outbound data, P - inside back connection, p - Phone-proxy TFTP connection,
>        q - SQL*Net data, R - outside acknowledged FIN,
>        R - UDP SUNRPC, r - inside acknowledged FIN, S - awaiting inside SYN,
>        s - awaiting outside SYN, T - SIP, t - SIP transient, U - up,
>        V - VPN orphan, W - WAAS,
>        X - inspected by service module,
>        x - per session, Y - director stub flow, y - backup stub flow,
>        Z - Scansafe redirection, z - forwarding stub flow
> ```

To understand what the flags represent, you need to understand TCP handshaking and connections. If you understand this about TCP, then it is easy to interpret the state of the connection. For example, the `UB` flags for a connection means that the connection has received an inbound ACK.

Comment: 'UB' means rec ACK then why it stuck at ACK not went further? In 'UIOB' ?

Comment: When you checked the connection, there had been no inbound or outbound data. Notice that what you have in your question says `bytes 0` for the line with the `UB` flags. The next line sent something out, and it has the `UIOB` flags and `bytes 561603`.

Comment: inbound and outbound in respect of which interface? How to find `ACK` received on inside interface or `ACK` going outbound?  In picture direction are little confusing.

Comment: That is inbound or outbound from the perspective of your network that is being protected by the firewall. If I understand your network correctly, people connect to your servers from outside, so the correct picture would be the one on the right with the server on the inside.

Answer (score 1):

It would be tricky as we look at the output of "show conn" with different interfaces rather than inside/outside only, especially the order of two interfaces in the output.

The below picture is from Cisco document [ASA TCP Connection Flags](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/113602-ptn-113602.html)

[image]

1. And I would like to use this to explain the following connnection:

   `TCP outside 10.23.232.217:443 inside 192.168.1.3:52427, idle 0:01:02, bytes 4504, flags UIO`

   We see that:

   - The **right side of the picture** (Server/Outside) is placed on **the left
     side of the "show conn" output**.
   - The Conn Flags **UIO** means: Three-way handshake (**U**) is completed and the inside host (192.168.1.3) initiated the traffic (we know that because there is **no Flag B** at all). inside host (192.168.1.3) has received data from and sent data to outside host (10.23.232.217) on TCP port 443 (**IO**)
   - In addition, by reading `TCP outside 10.23.232.217:443 inside 192.168.1.3:52427` only, we can also conclude who initiated the traffic by looking at their TCP port numbers. In this case inside host 192.168.1.3 initiated the https traffic to outside host 10.23.232.217 on TCP port 443.
2. Now back to your question, we should put the picture above together with Conn Flags and ASA interfaces:

   - Conn No.1 `TCP ext_dmz  10.5.8.40:33882 int_dmz  10.5.16.39:9090, idle 0:06:17, bytes 0, flags UB`: The ext_dmz host 10.5.8.40 (**right side of the picture**) initiated the traffic to int_dmz host 10.5.16.39 (**left side of the picture**) on TCP port 9090 (**UB**) but there is no data sent/received at that time at all.
   - Conn No.2 `TCP ext_dmz  10.5.8.40:60713 int_dmz  10.5.16.39:9090, idle 0:00:03, bytes 561603, flags UIOB`: similar to the connection above (**UB**), but now we see the ext_dmz host 10.5.8.40 sent data to and received the data from the int_dmz 10.5.16.39 (**IO**)
   - Conn No.3 `TCP ext_dmz  10.5.8.39:5432 int_dmz  10.5.16.40:53600, idle 0:00:06, bytes 44857, flags UIO`: the int_dmz host 10.5.16.40 (**left side of the picture**) initiated the traffic to the ext_dmz host 10.5.8.39 (**right side of the picture**) on TCP port 5432 (there is **no Flag B** at all and due to TCP port number). The int_dmz host 10.5.16.40 received data from and sent data to the ext_dmz host 10.5.8.39.
   - Conn No.4 `TCP outside  10.5.255.3:57229 inside 65.194.212.101:22, idle 0:00:45, bytes 395449, flags UIOB`: the outside host 10.5.255.3 (right side of the picture) initiated the traffic to the inside host/IP 65.194.212.101 (left side of the picture) on TCP port 22 (**UB**) and the outside host 10.5.255.3 sent data to and received data from (**IO**)

In additional, the Conn Flags **U** is a signal of a good (up) connection. You can check all UP connections by using the command `show conn state up`

I hope it is useful.

Comment: Hello can you Explain "B" little bit more and specifically what does this line means "(there is no Flag B at all and due to TCP port number)."

Comment: @Terminator 'B' means 'initial SYN from outside' or initial SYN from lower-security-level interface. We see this B Flag when traffic sourced from lower-security-level interface to reach resources on higher-security.level interface.